# C# forming Linq Query using .FindByExp

Tags: c#, linq

Table 1

```
Id    Name
1     Tank 1
2     Tank 2
3     Tank 3
4     Tank 4
```

Table 2

```
Id   Name
1    Tank 1
2    Tank 2
```

Result List it should return

```
Id    Name
1     Tank 1
2     Tank 2
3     Tank 3
4     Tank 4
```

I need to form a linq query using .FindByExp only. Like below i need to use joins and arrive at above list Result.

```
var tankLst = context.Tank.FindByExp(a => a.Id== S.Id).ToList();
```

Comment: Are we supposed to recognize FindByExp? Could you provide some context about this extension?

Comment: is this the library? https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/28073053/

Comment: It looks like the results are just the stuff in Table 1.

Comment: are you trying to implement this extension? can you be more specific what you want to achieve?

Answer (score -1):

```
var distinctNames = context.Table1.FindAll().Select(x=>x.Name).Distinct().ToArray();
var tab1 = context.Table1.FindAll().ToList();
var tab2 = context.Table2.FindAll().Where(x=> !distinctNames.Contains(x.Name)).ToList();
var resultList = tab1.Concat(tab2).OrderBy(x=>x.Name);
```

Comment: this is not what OP asked

Comment: No need to be sarcastic. please read the question more carefully. The OP has explicitly asked about a linq query "using .FindByExp". Does your answer solve that question?